# Bayesian Statistics

Tags: python, bayesian

I need to know how to find the Bayesian probability of two discrete distributions. For example the distributions are given as follows:

```
hypo_A=[ 0.1,0.4,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0]
hypo_B=[ 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.1]
```

With a prior of both of them being equally likely

The Bayesian formula is given `` p(x/H) = (p(H/x)*p(x))/(summation(p(H/x`)*p(x`))) ``.

Basically I need to know how to multiply these unequal distribution in python.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Do you mean $p(y|x)$, i.e. the probability of y conditioned on x? And what does `start` mean? If you're solely interested in a Python implementation, you may have better luck on SO.

Comment: Hi lalit, welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions here, it's generally expected that you will have had a go at it yourself, and are just asking for help fixing what you've got. So... have a go at it... even if it's just some psuedo code. Do some research using google or any books on python that you have... then come back here and *edit your question* and add all the results of your work and we can help you whip it into shape.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommended to read [Think Bayes](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/html/thinkbayes002.html) book.

Here is a simple implantation of Bayesian statistics with python I wrote:

```
from collections import namedtuple
hypothesis=namedtuple('hypothesis',['likelihood','belief'])
class DiscreteBayes:
    def __init__(self):
        """initiates the hypothesis list"""
        self.hypo=dict()
    def normalize(self):
        """normalizes the sum of all beliefs to 1"""
        s=sum([float(h.belief) for h in self.hypo.values()])
        self.hypo=dict([(k,hypothesis(likelihood=h.likelihood,belief=h.belief/s)) for k,h in self.hypo.items()])
    def update(self,data):
        """updates beliefs based on new data"""
        if type(data)!=list:
            data=[data]
        for datum in data:
            self.hypo=dict([(k,hypothesis(likelihood=h.likelihood,belief=h.belief*h.likelihood(datum))) for k,h in self.hypo.items()])
        self.normalize()
    def predict(self,x):
        """predict new data based on previously seen"""
        return sum([float(h.belief)*float(h.likelihood(x)) for h in self.hypo.values()])
```

In your case:

```
hypo_A = [ 0.1,0.4,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0]
hypo_B = [ 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.1]
d = DiscreteBayes()
d.hypo['hypo_A'] = hypothesis(likelihood=hypo_A.get ,belief=1)
d.hypo['hypo_B'] = hypothesis(likelihood=hypo_B.get ,belief=1)
d.normalize()
x = 1
d.update(x) #updating beliefs after seeing x
d.predict(x) #the probability of seeing x in the future
print (d.hypo)
```